# multiple numbers at different locations in a string variable

Tags: string, sas, substr

I have 7 digit numbers in a string variable but at different column for each record. below is the example of my data

```
ser       string
101      purchase items id: 1013456
102      entry no: 2017685
103      id: 1897654 item
.....
.....
```

My requirement is to create a new variable with just the numeric from `string` variable. Output should look like this

```
ser       number
101       1013456
102       2017685
103       1897654
```

I have the list of the numbers which can be created as a macro variable

```
%let num=1013456,2017685,1897654
```

I have used `scan` and `substr` functions but didn't get the desired result

I would appreciate any solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Are there ever any other numbers in your `string` variable? Are you always looking for a 7-digit number?

Comment: If the embedded number can have 8 or more digits you will need more than a simple regex pattern to ensure you are grabbing only 7-digit values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the numbers. Check out the PRX functions in SAS.

Here's an example of how to accomplish your goal using a regular expression:

```
data inData;
    length ser 8 string $100;

    ser = 101;
    string = 'purchase items id: 1013456';
    output;

    ser = 102;
    string = 'entry no: 2017685';
    output;

    ser = 103;
    string = 'id: 1897654 item';
    output;
run;

data outData;
    length ser 8 number $7;
    retain re;

    set inData;

    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        re = prxparse("/.*(\d{7}).*/");
    end;

    if prxmatch(re, string) then do; 
        number = prxposn(re, 1, string);
    end;

    keep ser number;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `compress()` function to remove the unwanted characters and the `input()` function to convert to a number.

```
data want;
set have;
number = input(compress(string,':','as'),7.);
drop string;
run;
```

The second argument to compress explicitly removes the `:` character.  The `as` modifier removes alphabetic characters (`a`) and space characters (`s`).

Comment: Alternatively you could just add `'kd'` as the modifier, which will keep only the digits

Comment: I always forget about that switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler regular expression approach using only `prxmatch`:

```
data have;
input ser string $50.;
cards;
101  purchase items id: 1013456
102  entry no: 2017685
103  id: 1897654 item
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  num = input(substr(string,prxmatch('/\d{7}/',string),7),8.);
run;
```

This will only match the first 7-digit number in `string`. By contrast, if it contains any other numbers then the `compress` approach will concatenate all of them.